# Mule Studio, Transform byte array into MySQL

Tags: mysql, magento, mule

I've got a Magento connection up and running and want to get all customers.
My subflow looks like this:

```
    <sub-flow name="listCustomers" doc:name="listCustomers">
    <magento:list-customers config-ref="MagentoConnecter" doc:name="Magento"/>
    <byte-array-to-object-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to Object"/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    </sub-flow>
```

which results into a string. But I'd like to insert the variables/customer data into a MySQL.
Do I need to use a foreach component?
And how can I address the variables then?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Foreach seems like a good way to achieve that.

The step to do are the following:

1. Transform the JSON representation into a list of maps using the [JSON Transformer](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Native+Support+for+JSON#NativeSupportforJSON-JSONTransformersAdded) (the returnClass will be java.util.Map)
2. Introduce the foreach scope
3. Within this scope insert a [jdbc outbound endpoint](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/JDBC+Transport+Reference#JDBCTransportReference-BasicInsertUpdateDelete) that performs the insert query

Comment: I'm struggling at the first point - do I need to use a transformer for this? Which one?

Comment: I've improved my answer based on your comment

Comment: I got a bit further. Implemented the transformer with all Setters and Getters and have a:
`<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="mypack.Person[]" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>`
component. But when I do a System.out.println in the method:
`public Object onCall`
it shows null. So the variables are not initialised - why that, any clues?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, ca you update the question with the transformer you are currently using?